# converting a Valid Json request to ArrayList

Tags: java, json

I have a valid json as shown

```
{

    "Items": "{one,two,three}"
}
```

**I need to map this to a ArrayList using ObjectMapper .**

But its not setting the values , please let me know .

I have tried this way

```
public class Hi {
    private static JsonHelper jsonHelper = JsonHelper.getInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyList yourData = mapper.readValue(new File("yourdata.json"),
                MyList.class);

    }

}


public class MyList {

    private ArrayList<String> Items= new ArrayList<String>();
    // setters and getters 

}
```

Comment: could anybody please tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"{one,two,three}" does not represent a list in json.  ["one", "two", "three"] is a list of three elements.

Comment: ditkin , i cant forget your help , that saved my day . Thank you very very much .

Answer (score 0):

json to be as follows

{
    "test": "test",
    "items": ["one","two","three"]
}